# Read in different data types from file

Tags: java, file, parsing

ONLY NEED EXPLANATION NO CODE NEEDED!!

I have to read in from a file where the format is `<double>, <double>` per line where the space and comma are also present. Currently I am reading in with a scanner.nextLine() and I want to know how to parse the String I get for the two doubles I need.

I am using java but not aloud to use pre-built third party libraries.

I have tried DatainputStream and BufferedReader also

Comment: FORMAT IS "<double>, <double>"

Comment: I assume you meant two double-precision floating-point numbers, separated by comma and space, without any quote characters at all, right?

Comment: `String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");` and then parse the pair of tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner.nextLine()` is very slow, so it's better to use `BufferedReader`.

You can then use `indexOf()` and `substring()`:

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath)) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        int idx = line.indexOf(", ");
        if (idx == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid line: " + line);
        double d1, d2;
        try {
            d1 = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0, idx));
            d2 = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(idx + 2));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid line: " + line, e);
        }
        // code using d1 and d2 here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is split string

```
String string = "4.0,3.2";
String[] results = string.split(",");
String firstDouble = results[0];
String secondDouble = results[1];
```

and then parse the results to double

```
Double double = Double.parseDouble(firstDouble);
```